# What is the best way to use a Login Activity with pull to refresh

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to create an App that:

- Login to a website via Jsoup (or something like that)
- Sync and pull refresh
- Offline content

What i did until now:

- MainActivity is a Navigation Drawer
- LoginActivity is opened when the MainActivity has not login credencials in the prefs
- When login succefulls, the LoginActivity is finished and return to the MainActivity (dont know how to pass infos between the activities).

I would to know if there is a better way to do that things and if there is a best way to control login and activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very similar way of doing things in most app that integrate the Android "Account Manager" : you launch your main activity, ask the "account manager" to get credentials for your app (or if there is no account, an "add account" screen is presented), if the credentials are up to date you can go on. Otherwise the login and credential updates are transfered to the authenticator part. Communication is usually done with "intents".

So I guess you choose the right way of doing things. With the account manager, things are a little bit easier and a little bit secure but it requires a good understanding of the account manager way of implementing things.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

I made one a long time ago based on this tutorial :

http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/

(But I don't know if it's still up to date).

Comment: Thanks. This will fit my needs.